# Why doesn't my search work when I use Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm making a simple search engine for my Laravel 5 app. As it's only small, I'm just using a FULLTEXT index on my main table. I'm trying to use Vue.js to avoid a page reload.

In my SearchController I simply have:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->search;

        $results = Product::whereRaw("MATCH (product_name, product_description) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($search))->get(array('product_name','slug'));

        return $results;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
getResults: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.$http.get('api/search', function(search){
            this.$set('searchResults', search);
        });
}
```

and the form:

```
{!! Form::open(['v-on' => 'submit: getResults($event)', 'method' => 'get', 'action' => 'SearchController@search']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('search','Search:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('search', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'v-model' => 'search']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'form-control btn btn-primary']) !!}
        </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

If I remove Vue.js from the equation, the form submits and I get a nice JSON object of search results. If I put it through Vue.js, I just get an empty object. I'm using the same search term in both cases.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I've logged `search` to the console in my `getResults` function, and it's empty, which explains things a little. But why is it empty? If I echo out the data search is populated as I type by Vue's 2-way binding, so `search` definitely is not empty...

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't send anything with vueJS. No data are sent with the ajax request. You need to do something like that.

```
this.$http.get('api/search', this.search , function(search){
        this.$set('searchResults', search);
    });
```

Comment: No dice. Should I be `POST`ing the query instead?

Comment: You can try using post, but it should work with get too. But i think it is because you need to sent an object like that: {data : this.search} ? @user4676723

Comment: Or just try this url : 'api/search?search='+this.search

Comment: Hmm. The passed data doesn't _have_ to be an object, it can be a string too, according to the docs

Comment: According to the docs you can use both that's true ahah. What do you get when you use the url with the parameters in Laravel ? If you put a `dd($request->search)` then ?

Comment: If I go through Vue, a load of Javascript. If I hit the route in the address bar, I get the search query as expected...